# Using default implementations to superpower flags enums with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, enum, entity-framework-core

I would like to share this post with the community since at first glance it is very promising. Storing flags in the database is something that I have been interested in doing for a while since it seems like a lean way to store some bit options which become ugly with Is[this], Is[That], and Is[Whatever]. However, I have never really come across an implementation that drew my attention.

So, I came up with one one my own which uses C#.NET-8.0. The goal is to create some code that is not cluttered but allows the user to apply bit flags to models with ease. The best way to start is to show how I would like the code to be consumed. This is actually the most basic part. The model is Hypercomb(which represents a software project I am building). I won't make it generic yet, just to be simple. The following code needs to be clean as possible in both use and implementation:

```
// 1. Create a simple standard way to turn flag options on and off 
//    for POCO objects.
var hypercomb = new Hypercomb();
hypercomb.Set(x => x.LockOn());
hypercomb.Set(x => x.LockOff());
// ...

// 2. Create properties to bind against and do conditional logic with.
if (hypercomb.IsLocked) { ...}
if (hypercomb.IsHidden) { ...}
if (hypercomb.IsReadOnly) { ...}
// ... 

// an interface with some access implementations 
public interface IHypercombFlags
{
    HypercombFlags Flags { get; set; }
    void CenterOn() => Flags |= HypercombFlags.Center;
    void CenterOff() => Flags &= ~HypercombFlags.Center;
    void LockOn() => Flags |= HypercombFlags.Locked;
    void LockOff() => Flags &= ~HypercombFlags.Locked;
    void EditorOn() => Flags |= HypercombFlags.Editor;
    void EditorOff() => Flags &= ~HypercombFlags.Editor;
    void HideOn() => Flags |= HypercombFlags.Hidden;
    void HideOff() => Flags &= ~HypercombFlags.Hidden;
    void HypercellOn() => Flags |= HypercombFlags.Hypercell;
    void HypercellOff() => Flags &= ~HypercombFlags.Hypercell;
    void ReadOnlyOn() => Flags |= HypercombFlags.Readonly;
    void ReadOnlyOff() => Flags &= ~HypercombFlags.Readonly;
    void ToggleHypercell() => Flags ^= HypercombFlags.Hypercell;
}

// the model associated with the preceding sample code:
public class Hypercomb : IHypercombFlags
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public HypercombFlags Flags { get; set; }  /// FLAGS
    public HexagonAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
    public bool IsHypercell { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Hypercomb> Items { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public Hypercomb Source { get; set; }
    public int? SourceId { get; set; }
    public string VoiceActivationText { get; set; }
    public bool IsCenter => Flags.HasFlag(HypercombFlags.Center);
    public bool IsLocked => Flags.HasFlag(HypercombFlags.Locked);
    public bool IsEditor => Flags.HasFlag(HypercombFlags.Editor);
    public bool IsHidden => Flags.HasFlag(HypercombFlags.Hidden);
    public bool IsReadOnly => Flags.HasFlag(HypercombFlags.Readonly);
}
```

Next, I have a class to store a bunch of bit-flags that will map to the values of an enum. The field are in numerical order and MUST never change once set.

```
public class HypercombMappings
{
    // CRITICAL DO NOT CHANGE THESE VALUES 
    // ->  Mapped to database bits in the Flags field
    public const uint NONE = 0x0;
    public const uint EDITOR = 0x1;
    public const uint HIDDEN = 0x2;
    public const uint LOCKED = 0x4;
    public const uint CENTER = 0x8;
    public const uint READONLY = 0x10;
    public const uint HYPERCELL = 0x20;
    // CRITICAL DO NOT CHANGE THESE VALUES 
    // but add more until you run out.
}
```

The purpose of the preceding list of constants is so that as I add new enum values, I can still visually sort them.

```
[Flags]
public enum HypercombFlags : uint
{
    None = HypercombMappings.NONE,
    Center = HypercombMappings.CENTER,
    Editor = HypercombMappings.EDITOR,
    Hidden = HypercombMappings.HIDDEN,
    Hypercell = HypercombMappings.HYPERCELL,
    Locked = HypercombMappings.LOCKED,
    Readonly = HypercombMappings.READONLY
}
```

Then finally, the glue is a simple extension method to allow for the final product.

```
// This is to tie it together so that options can be set conveniently through the 
// the flags interface.
public static class HypercombExtensionMethods
{
    public static void Set(this IHypercombFlags hypercomb,
   Action<IHypercombFlags> action)
    {
        action.Invoke(hypercomb);
    }
}
```

I will continue to refine this but it is working very nicely so far.

Comment: Keep in mind this is the Code Review Site and not Stack Overflow, we need to see more than the minimum code to do a good review. Where are the using statements? How are you using this code? This is borderline too theoretical. You might want to review [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It was fun coding and a great though exercise but you could be right.

Comment: Are those `{ ...}` blocks real C#?  That's not a syntax I've come across before.

Comment: @TobySpeight It's not C#.

Comment: Surely, it is C# 8.0 and was compiled as so. Maybe you are talking about the function wrapped to another line. I will add the newer version shortly.

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Comment: @TobySpeight. Can you tell me how to get that code back from the rollback so I can more easily put it in an answer?

Comment: If you look in the [edit history](/posts/275352/revisions), you should be able to view the previous version.  You probably want to copy from the [last edit before the rollback](/2edb905c-c92a-412b-a525-20d595500641/view-source).

Answer (score 6):

What are you getting that you couldn't get with properties?

```
public class Hypercomb
{
    // Mapped as field, not part of the public interface - it's an implementation detail
    private HypercombFlags _flags = 0;
    
    // Ignored in persistence mapping
    public bool IsCenter
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _flags.HasFlag(HypercombFlags.Center);
        }
        set 
        { 
            if (value)
                _flags |= HypercombFlags.Center;
            else
                _flags &= ~HypercombFlags.Center;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the API of your class is easy and natural to use. EF Core can happily ignore the properties on top of the flags and map the flags to one column.

There might be more benefits to your solution that aren't clear without more example uses but it looks like it's overcomplicating the problem.

Comment: Appreciated, I went with a more generic solution solution and it is working great. I will add it to the post shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new implementation that I am more fond of. It has property change notification included. Also, it is fully functional copy paste into .net core .5 application(although, split it up to remove scrolling in the code example). The difference here is that I am using custom attribute and reflection in this rendition.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace FlagEnum
{

I added some implementations for changing values. Since the binding aspect is out of scope of the example I will just say it is working in WPF quite well.

```
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hypercomb = new Model();

        var added = Flags.Hidden;
        Console.WriteLine($"adding: {added}");
        hypercomb.SetFlags(added);
        Console.WriteLine($"result: {hypercomb.Flags}");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        added = Flags.Readonly | Flags.Center | Flags.Locked | Flags.ShowCaption;
        Console.WriteLine($"adding: {added}");
        hypercomb.SetFlags(added);
        Console.WriteLine($"result: {hypercomb.Flags}");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        var removed = Flags.Readonly;
        Console.WriteLine($"removing: {removed}");
        hypercomb.RemoveFlags(removed);
        Console.WriteLine($"result: {hypercomb.Flags}");
        Console.WriteLine("");

        var toggled = Flags.Locked | Flags.ShowCaption;
        Console.WriteLine($"toggling: {toggled}");
        hypercomb.Toggle(toggled);
        Console.WriteLine($"result: {hypercomb.Flags}");
        
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Here are some extension methods to support getting the required property metadata for change notifications.

```
public static class EnumExtensionMethods
{

    // get the names from the given flags argument
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetNames<T>(this uint flags)
    {
        var flagobj = Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), flags)!;
        var list = flagobj.ToString()!.Split(",");
        return list.Select(x => x.Trim());
    }

    // get the description for on property changed from 
    // DescriptionAttributes
    public static string? FindDescription<T>(this T source, string name)
    {
        var memInfo = typeof(T).GetMember(name).First();
        var attribute = memInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DescriptionAttribute>().First();
        return attribute!.Description;
    }
}
```

This is the base class for enum operations with notification change support.

```
public abstract class NotifyPropertyChangedFlagsBase<T> : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
    where T : Enum
{
    private T _flags;

    public T Flags
    {
        get => _flags;
        protected set => _flags = value;
    }

    // generic function to set one or more flags
    public void SetFlags(T flags)
    {
        // set the new flag
        var added = (uint)(object)flags;
        var existing = (uint)(object)_flags;
        var newflags = existing | added;
        SetFlagInstance(newflags);
    }
    
    // generic function to remove one or more flags
    public void RemoveFlags(T flags)
    {
        // remove the flags
        var removed = (uint)(object)flags;
        var existing = (uint)(object)_flags;
        var newflags = existing & ~removed;
        SetFlagInstance(newflags);
    }
```

// opt-in scrolling for code examples would be a better experience for some.
-- continued...

```
    // set the actual Flags property instance
    private void SetFlagInstance(uint newflags)
    {
        var newobject = (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), newflags);
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_flags, newobject)) return;

        // set the value/
        _flags = newobject;

        var names = newflags.GetNames<T>();
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            var description = _flags.FindDescription(name)!;
            OnPropertyChanged(description);
        }
    }

    // generic function to toggle one or more flags
    public void Toggle(T flags)
    {
        // toggle the flags
        var toggled = (uint)(object)flags;
        var existing = (uint)(object)_flags;
        var newflags = existing ^ toggled;

        SetFlagInstance(newflags);
    }
}
```